# ¿Con qué algoritmo puedo obtener todos los pares de 2 divisores dada la factorización de un número entero?

Tags: algoritmos

Teniendo la factorización de un número entero positivo quiero obtener todas las combinaciones de 2 divisores de ese número.

Por ejemplo: `144 = 2*2*2*2*3*3` una combinación de divisores sería `144 = 2*72`, otra sería `144 = 12*12` y otra sería `144 = 4*36`. Y existen varias combinaciones más para ese número.

Elegí para el ejemplo el número 144 pero puede ser cualquier numero entero positivo.

Comment: Hola @Pedro Urday!! ¿Qué lenguaje utilizas? ¿Qué código tienes hasta ahora y qué has intentado con qué resultados? Creo que sería bueno conocer estas cosas para responder mejor a tu pregunta. Puede aprovechar a revisar [Cómo hacer una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y añadir algún detalle más. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre el siguiente algoritmo:

- Tenemos los factores en una lista, por ejemplo `[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]`
- El número `N` será el producto de todos los elementos de la lista (ej: 144)
- Tomamos los elementos de esa lista de uno en uno, y:

  - factor1 será el valor de ese elemento
  - factor2 será N/factor1 (división entera)
- Tomamos todas las combinaciones de dos elementos de esa lista, y para cada combinación:

  - factor1 será el producto de los elementos en esa combinación
  - factor2 será N/factor1
- Tomamos todas las combinaciones de tres elementos de esa lista, y para cada combinación:

  - factor1 será el producto de los elementos en esa combinación
  - factor2 será N/factor1
- etc.. (combinaciones de 4 elementos, de 5... )
- Nos detenemos cuando el tamaño de las combinaciones sea la mitad de la lista (pues a partir de aquí saldrán casos repetidos)

De hecho el algoritmo anterior también genera casos repetidos, pues por ejemplo en su primera iteración va obteniendo repetidas veces el 2 como primer factor. Así que para eliminar duplicados se pueden ir guardando las parejas `(factor1, factor2)` en un conjunto (o estructura de datos equivalente que sólo añada elementos si no estaban ya ahí). Para evitar que se nos añada por ejemplo la combinación (8,18) y más tarde (18,8), podemos hacer que dentro de estas parejas los elementos estén ordenados de menor a mayor.

Una implementación en Python de estas ideas:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations

def prod(lista):
  """Calcula el producto de los elementos de la lista"""
  return reduce(mul, lista, 1)

def parejas_divisores(factores):
  n = prod(factores)
  resultado = set()  # Conjunto inicialmente vacío
  for tamaño in range(1, len(factores)//2+1):
    for parte1 in combinations(factores, tamaño):
      factor1 = prod(parte1)
      factor2 = n//factor1
      resultado.add((min(factor1, factor2), max(factor1, factor2)))
  return sorted(resultado)
```

Ejemplo/demo de uso:

```
factores = [2,2,2,2,3,3]
for p in parejas_divisores(factores):
  print(p)
```

Genera:

```
(2, 72)
(3, 48)
(4, 36)
(6, 24)
(8, 18)
(9, 16)
(12, 12)
```

Comment: Es justo lo que buscaba. Gracias!